# Explore package on Gazebo & Turtlebot

Tags: gazebo, exploration, turtlebot, explore, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to use the explore package (frontier based exploration) with stage without problem. Now, I would like to use it with Gazebo and in the real world. I am using robots similar to the Turtlebot (Create base + IMU + Asus camera). I have tried modifying the explore/stage launch file (see below), but it didn't work (I don't see anything in the Rviz map, and the robot doesn't move). How can I fix this?

[Edit] Here is the Wiki for the explore package:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore

[Edit 2] Basically, this url shows what I want to do, but with the PR2 instead of the Turtlebot. I tried following his steps, but I still get no movement in Gazebo and no map in Rviz.
http://answers.ros.org/question/33590/map-resolution-issue-between-explore-and-pr2_2dnav_slam/

[Edit 3] Here is the original explore_stage launch file and its rostopic list output:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <node pkg="stage" type="stageros" name="stage" args="$(find stage)/world/willow-erratic.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="gmapping" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan" />
    <param name="inverted_laser" value="false" />
    <param name="maxUrange" value="30.0" />
    <param name="particles" value="30" />
    <param name="delta" value="0.10" />
    <param name="xmin" value="-15.0" />
    <param name="xmax" value="15.0" />
    <param name="ymin" value="-15.0" />
    <param name="ymax" value="15.0" />
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5" />
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="1.0" />
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="1.0" />
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.3" />
    <param name="llsamplerange" value ="0.05" />
    <param name="llsamplestep" value ="0.05" />
    <param name="lasamplerange" value ="0.05" />
    <param name="lasamplestep" value ="0.05" />
  </node>
  <include file="$(find explore_stage)/move.xml" />
  <include file="$(find explore_stage)/explore_slam.xml" />
  
</launch>

OUTPUT:
    /base_pose_ground_truth
    /base_scan
    /clock
    /cmd_vel
    /explore/explore_costmap/inflated_obstacles
    /explore/explore_costmap/obstacles
    /explore/explore_costmap/parameter_descriptions
    /explore/explore_costmap/parameter_updates
    /explore/explore_costmap/robot_footprint
    /explore/explore_costmap/unknown_space
    /explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
    /explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
    /explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
    /explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
    /explore/explore_planner/plan
    /explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
    /explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
    /explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
    /explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
    /explore/loop_closure_planner/plan
    /explore/map
    /gmapping/entropy
    /map
    /map_metadata
    /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
    /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
    /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
    /move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
    /move_base/NavfnROS/plan
    /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/cost_cloud
    /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan
    /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/local_plan
    /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions
    /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_updates
    /move_base/cancel
    /move_base/current_goal
    /move_base/feedback
    /move_base/global_costmap/inflated_obstacles
    /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles
    /move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions
    /move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates
    /move_base/global_costmap/robot_footprint
    /move_base/global_costmap/unknown_space
    /move_base/goal
    /move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
    /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles
    /move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions
    /move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates
    /move_base/local_costmap/robot_footprint
    /move_base/local_costmap/unknown_space
    /move_base/parameter_descriptions
    /move_base/parameter_updates
    /move_base/result
    /move_base/status
    /move_base_simple/goal
    /odom
    /rosout
    /rosout_agg
    /tf
    /visualization_marker
    /visualization_marker_array
```

[Edit 4]
I modified the launch file and made some progress. Now, I can accurately see the gmapping map in Rviz. However, there are two issues. First, Rviz displays the explore map, but it's blank (ignore the camera height, that's normal):

[image].

Secondly, the robot moved only once in Gazebo; it rotated by 90 degrees and then stopped moving completely.

When running explore on Gazebo, I get a lot of warnings from the terminal, and my computer becomes really slow (4 CPUs are used between 90-100%):

```
[ WARN] [1369766566.516970091, 12.321000000]: The base_scan observation buffer has not been updated for 4.03 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.20 seconds.
[ WARN] [1369766567.986540211, 12.378000000]: [/move_base]:Sensor data is out of date, we're not going to allow commanding of the base for safety
[ WARN] [1369766568.061583553, 12.380000000]: Entropy has not been updated. Loop closure opportunities may be ignored.
```

Here are my 2 launch files. I use 2 files to reduce the amount of warnings I get on the same terminal.

1.

```
<launch>
     <master auto="start"/>
      <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
       
      <!--- Run gazebo --> 
      <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-u $(find turtlebot_gazebo)/worlds/empty.world" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
      <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui" />  
    
      <!--- Turtlebot -->
      <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot.urdf.xacro'" />
    
      <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model turtlebot"   respawn="false" output="screen"/>
      
    </launch>
```

2. ```
       <!--- Set up Turtlebot -->  
       <node pkg="diagnostic_aggregator" type="aggregator_node" name="diagnostic_aggregator" >
         <rosparam command="load" file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/config/diagnostics.yaml" />
       </node>

       <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
         <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0" />
       </node>

       <!-- The odometry estimator -->
       <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
         <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
         <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
         <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
         <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
         <param name="imu_used" value="false"/>
         <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
         <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
       </node>

       <!-- throttling -->
       <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager" respawn="true">
         <param name="max_rate" value="20.0"/>
         <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
         <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
       </node>

       <!-- Fake Laser -->
       <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager" respawn="true">
         <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
         <!-- heights are in the (optical?) frame of the kinect -->
         <param name="min_height" value="-0.15"/>
         <param name="max_height" value="0.15"/>
         <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
       </node>

       <!-- Fake Laser (narrow one, for localization -->
       <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser_narrow" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager" respawn="true">
         <param name="output_frame_id" value="/camera_depth_frame"/>
         <!-- heights are in the (optical?) frame of the kinect -->
         <param name="min_height" value="-0.025"/>
         <param name="max_height" value="0.025"/>
         <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
         <remap from="scan" to="/narrow_scan"/>
       </node>

       <!--- Run explore -->
       <include file="$(find explore_gazebo)/move.xml" />
         <include file="$(find explore_gazebo)/explore_slam.xml" />  

       <!--- Run gmapping -->
       <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/config/gmapping_turtlebot.launch" />

     </launch>
   ```

Here is the rostopic list when running explore & Gazebo:

```
/base_scan
/camera/camera_info
/camera/depth/points
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/clock
/cmd_vel
/depth/camera_info
/depth/image_raw
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/diagnostics_toplevel_state
/explore/explore_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/explore/explore_costmap/obstacles
/explore/explore_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/explore/explore_costmap/parameter_updates
/explore/explore_costmap/robot_footprint
/explore/explore_costmap/unknown_space
/explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
/explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
/explore/explore_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
/explore/explore_planner/plan
/explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
/explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
/explore/loop_closure_planner/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
/explore/loop_closure_planner/plan
/explore/map
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/gmapping/entropy
/imu/data
/initialpose
/joint_states
/map
/map_metadata
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/NavfnROS/NavfnROS_costmap/unknown_space
/move_base/NavfnROS/plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/cost_cloud
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/local_plan
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/parameter_updates
/move_base/cancel
/move_base/current_goal
/move_base/feedback
/move_base/global_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/global_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/global_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/global_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/global_costmap/unknown_space
/move_base/goal
/move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/obstacles
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/local_costmap/parameter_updates
/move_base/local_costmap/robot_footprint
/move_base/local_costmap/unknown_space
/move_base/parameter_descriptions
/move_base/parameter_updates
/move_base/result
/move_base/status
/move_base_simple/goal
/odom
/robot_pose_ekf/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/set_hfov
/set_update_rate
/slam_gmapping/entropy
/tf
/turtlebot_node/sensor_state
/visualization_marker
/visualization_marker_array
```

[Edit 5] Here is the rxgraph that I have. Wouldn't I need to connect one of the Kinect_Laser nodes to move_base? How can I do that? I'm quite a newbie...

[image: image description]

[Edit 6] I just made a little progress. I modified costmap_common.yaml and now the robot is moving around (very very slowly). The map is still blank and I still receive warnings related to base_scans. Here's what I changed (but I don't even know what I'm doing!).

```
map_type: costmap
transform_tolerance: 0.5
obstacle_range: 2.5
max_obstacle_height: 2.0
raytrace_range: 3.0
inscribed_radius: 0.35
circumscribed_radius: 0.4
inflation_radius: 0.6
cost_scaling_factor: 15.0
lethal_cost_threshold: 100

observation_sources: base_scan   **//Changed this to kinect_laser**

base_scan: {sensor_frame: base_laser_link, data_type: LaserScan, expected_update_rate: 0.2,
  observation_persistance: 0.0, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63613/explore-package-on-gazebo-&-turtlebot/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-27**:
Please provide more information about how it didn't work.  We cannot see how it did not work. Please provide enough information to reproduce what you are doing and what you expect it to do and what you observe it doing.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-27**:
What is the result of `rostopic` when you run the launch file with stage (only) and how does it compare with the output of rostopic after running the modified launch file?

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-28**:
I've done that yesterday to pinpoint the problem, but I wasn't sure what to do next. I'll post the results in my first post in a few minutes.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-28**:
Alright, I made some progress, but the problem isn't solved yet. I'll clean up my first post because it's filled with useless information.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-28**:
After the robot turns 90 degrees, are there any messages being sent?  You can check useful sounding topics like.. `rostopic echo /cmd_vel`, `rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal`, etc.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-28**:
I only get this in cmd_vel: linear:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.0
angular:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.0

And goal outputs: "Is /clock being published?"

I think the problem is related to the 3 warnings I posted above. There might be a wrong parameter, but I don't even know which could cause that.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-28**:
Can you also check /base_scan topic (rostopic echo /base_scan)?

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-29**:
I get this: "WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?"

By the way, thanks a lot for all your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that your kinect_laser is publishing on topic /scan but move_base and gmapping expect it to be on topic /base_scan. So first undo your change on costmap_common.yaml, and add this remap on your  node:

```
<remap from="scan" to="/base_scan"/>
```

after the

```
<remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
```

Then type

```
rostopic info /scan
```

and

```
rostopic info /base_scan
```

to check that everybody is subscribed to /base_scan

**Update**
Yeap, you must remap everything to /scan or to /base_scan. Let's use /scan:

- Remove the  on Fake laser
- Rename base_scan as scan on costmap_common.yaml
- Add  in the explore launch file

/base_scan topic should disapear, and /scan should have 1 publisher and 3 subscribers

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-30**:
So I followed your suggestion, but the result is the same. Rostopic info is as follows:

rostopic info /scan
Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Publishers:

- /gazebo (http://localhost:41083/)

Subscribers:  * /slam_gmapping (http://localhost:51813/)

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-30**:
rostopic info /base_scan
Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Publishers: None

Subscribers:

- /explore (http://localhost:40629/)
- /move_base (http://localhost:39869/)

I assume the problem comes from the fact there is no publisher here?

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-30**:
By the way, I was wrong when I said Stage was working fine; it also generates all these warnings repetitively. However, the robot behaves as expected in this case.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-31**:
Alright, so now I have this:

Publishers:

- /gazebo (http://localhost:51156/)

Subscribers:

- /slam_gmapping (http://localhost:37441/)
- /move_base (http://localhost:60119/)
- /explore (http://localhost:38308/)

However, I still get the warnings and the robot is standing still.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-31**:
I see a map though (I actually modified explore to use the gmapping map). Maybe the problem lies in move.xml? Or maybe it's just a publishing frequency issue?
Also, rostopic hz scan returns: "no new messages
average rate: 14.860
min: 0.050s max: 0.144s std dev: 0.02170s window: 175
"  many times

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-31**:
I just set the expected_update_rate in costmap_common.yaml to 0.0, and the robot moves around. But that's not a good solution. And besides, the gmapping map only gets generated once at the beginning. It stays the same afterwards even if the robot explores.

I'll be back on Monday.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-02**:
mmm...  curious the "no new messages"... if you echo scan topic, you get readings continuously? if gmapping don't receive scans, he doesn't update the map

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-03**:
I finally fixed the problem! After adding your suggestion, I had not noticed there was a ros node running in the background. I killed it, and now it's working perfectly fine in both Gazebo (even though it's very slow) and in the real world. This was a silly problem. Thanks so much for your help!!!

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-03**:
However, I still get this warning, but hopefully it doesn't make much of a difference: "Entropy has not been updated. Loop closure opportunities may be ignored.
"

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-03**:
But it still keeps building the map? I think you get this warning when no scan are received....

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-04**:
It seems to be building the map fine... I haven't ran the simulation on big environments for extended periods of time yet, but from what I've seen it works.